# Giving programmatical shape change animation to image in corona SDK

Tags: animation, coronasdk

in my corona game, I need to give a `flag like animation` `(fully programatically, without using extra sprites or spritesheets)` to a rectangle image. Can anyone know how to do that to my following code:

```
local myTile = display.newImage("myTile.png",150,50)
myTile.x = 160
myTile.y = 160
```

**eg**: my Image is as below:

[image]

And what I need is, like the following:

[image]

Comment: why 'down voted'..? Am I asking a question that is infair to stackoverflow community? I'm not thinking so. I have specified my need in my question(and it is not fully impossible, because I found something near to the solution). I've posted the basic code too. If you don't know the answer, then please do not diverse others from the question by downvoting it. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Corona SDK just released Graphics 2.0 beta to paid accounts.  It allows for advanced functionality and distorting graphics but nothing this complex.

From your image what you're wanting is a cloth rendering functionality.  Sadly I don't think you'll find this in Corona SDK.  You could get something like this in Unity 3D that is a lot more powerful with 3D shapes and rendering.

I've dug through the APIs a bit and haven't seen anything that could provide this for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have should move the image. I think you're trying to simply change the shape of the image, you'll need an image rectangle to do that.

try this out

```
local myTile = display.newImageRect("myTile.png", 150, 50, imageWidth, imageHeight)
myTile.xScale = 1.1
myTile.yScale = 0.9
```

source: 
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newImageRect.html

Comment: hi friend, thank you for the help. But I do not need simple scale. I am in need of a waving flag like shape change to a rect or an image. If you know that, please help me